# Does iTunes Connect allow tracking of return user activity?

Tags: app-store-connect

We're regularly downloading iTunes connect app download data but haven't figured out how to identify return user downloads from new customers. Same thing with Google Play activity actually. Does Apple (Google) make return activity accessible at all, or is it up to authors to create an additional interface to capture return activity? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple does not provide such a service.
If you wanted to have data about users returning to the app, DAU (daily average users) or track any other user behavior, you should use a third-party SDK.
There are many out there, some free and some paid. As an example and a place to start, two well-known services:

- [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com). It is free (in other words, you share your users' info with them: that's the payment).
- HasOffers' [Mobile App Tracking](http://www.hasoffers.com/wiki/Application_Support%3aMobile_App_Tracking). It is a paid service.

Comment: Can't upvote unfortunately. Thanks for the info, and the two leads!